# Cutting of Magnetic Flux

Tags: magnetic-fields, earth, textbook-erratum

My book reads :

> If a player runs along north south direction, no magnetic field lines are cut.

So my question is that how is this possible because the vertical lines are still perpendicular to his motion, so why is no potential difference induced?

Comment: A simple diagram would be helpful, since it is not quite clear to me what you mean by vertical lines.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the player is carrying a horizontal rod.

Your response is correct, though I would word it differently. Over most of the Northern hemisphere the Earth's magnetic field has a vertically downward component and a horizontal component that points roughly North. But it would be confusing to represent these components with two sets of magnetic field lines. Instead, we show the *resultant* field by lines slanting into the ground.

Nonetheless your response is right in principle: the rod will still cut the (slanting) field lines, or will cut the vertical component of the field, so an emf will be induced. The exception is near the equator, where the vertical component is zero, that is the field lines are horizontal.

To visualise the Earth's field, imagine a small bar magnet to be placed near the centre of the Earth, with its (magnetic) South pole pointing roughly North geographically. You can then sketch the pattern of magnetic field lines, noting the angles at which they intersect the a circle centred on the magnet, representing the Earth's surface.